Unexpected output distortion when driving MOSFETs with SPWM in LTspice
The first picture below is the circuit diagram. SPWM was used, a full bridge structure and bootstrap circuit was used for the high side MOSFETs.
Datasheet IXTH88N30P
The carrier signal is 10 kHz and the AC reference signal is 50 Hz.
When I increased the frequency of the carrier signal to 10 kHz, I noticed that there was distortion in the signals going to the MOSFETs. Everything was working fine before increasing the frequency of the signal.
2nd picture is the SPWM.
3rd picture (red signal) is the distorted signal going to the MOSFET.
The 4th picture (blue signal) is the resulting distorted signal at the gate of the MOSFET.
The 5th picture is zoomed in view of gate of the M1.
The 6th picture is zoomed in view of gate of the M2.
Why does the signal get distorted like this when I increase the frequency? What could be the reason for this?

Source: My own study

Source: My own study

Source: My own study

Source: My own study

Source: My own study

Source: My own study

Source: My own study

Source : my own simulation

Source : my own simulation

Source : my own simulationn

Please post zoomed in oscillograms of M1 and M2 Vgs in the same plot.

I updated @winny

Please overlay in the same plot plane and zoom in on one or two switchings. And the blue one is not Vgs. Click and hold to drag the measurement across two nodes to measure the difference. Otherwise you get the Vg with respect to ground.

What are the op-amps? Are you sure you mean to use large resistors to drive a 180nC Qg transistor?

We want to reduce the gate voltage of the high side FETs to the source voltage, not necessarily ground. If I had to take a guess at the immediate issue, it may be that.
I have a problem with a few parts of this circuit, notably the gate drive portion.

Source: You
It looks like what you're doing is running the signal through an op-amp buffer (which is good practice, but maybe not entirely necessary for this implementation of the circuit), then running it through two voltage amplifiers/inverters (the PNP and the NPN can be seen as voltage amps, buffers, and inverters). This part is unnecessary and kinda not the greatest way of doing a gate drive circuit. I remember seeing this circuit from an electronoobs vid and I started there too, but I quickly found out that there are better options.
First I will say that the most time and Cost effective option is to just buy a gate driver from a pre-existing Manufacturer off of Digikey or something.
If you are dead-set on building your own and want to use all discrete components (aside from a few comparators and AND gates), then buckle up.
GATE DRIVER DESIGN

Source: Me
This is a picture of a gate driver for a half-bridge I threw together in an hour or two (I had one previously made).
It may seem daunting at first, but it's really not that bad once you know what you're doing. I took the time to label everything in LTspice so that you can have an idea what section does what.
VOLTAGES

source: me
The "voltages" section is your reference voltages. They do not need to be precise, just 'ballpark' more or less. 12 V can be anywhere from 8-18 V, but 12 V is more convenient. Can't be less than 8 though. 5 V is typical microcontroller and logic voltage, so we need that for our logic section. 2.5 V is for our comparators to use as a reference voltage. You will want to use comparators with Schmitt triggering in your final circuit, as these don't have it and only work because this is a simulation. Or, you can just use proper logic buffer ICs with schmitt triggering and skip making the 2.5V reference entirely as they will have this internally.
The far left side of the image is the voltage source that is our PWM input. It is some duty cycle, I chose 50% to make it easy and its roughly the same switching times as your current system. This can be changed out for whatever you have currently, I just used it for testing.
DEAD-TIME

source: me
To the immediate right of that you have the dead time circuitry for the high side and the low side. There is also a pulldown resistor so that the input signals aren't as susceptible to noise. The signal from the MCU goes into both the high side and low side at the same time, and the low side is inverted from the high side later on.
First, the signal is buffered by U4, U6, U10, and U11. One copy of the signal then goes into an AND gate, while the second copy goes into an RC filter. This drastically slows the rise time of that signal, turning it from a square wave into more of a triangle wave.
This is awesome because we can use a comparator to compare the slowed signal to a reference voltage, and once the signal rises to that voltage, the output will be high. The AND gate will detect that both copies of the signal are high, and output HIGH. This means that there is a distinct time-delay from when the untouched copy of the input signal goes high and when the output goes high.
The reason the signal goes into an NPN transistor is so that we have no dead-time on turnoff. If we had dead-time on turnoff, we would have just delayed the entire PWM signal instead of just the rising edge, which would be pointless.
The NPN instantly drains the capacitor once biased, so we can instantly turn off. The dead-time can be adjusting by either increasing the value of the capacitor or the resistor in the RC filter. I suggest increasing the value of capacitor, as it leads to less issues with noise.
OPTOCOUPLER

source: me
The high side signal then goes into an optocoupler. This isolates the grounds, which is CRITICAL as the high side MOSFET is not referenced to ground. If you don't know how optocouplers work, a quick google search should resolve that. They're really cool.
BOOTSTRAP

source: me
I've neglected to make the bootstrap section any better as it is outside the scope of the question, but you CAN make it work with 100% duty cycles using something called a charge pump. Google that, there's a fantastic Texas Instruments whitepaper on it. The bootstrap section in the pic above is the same as yours.
The important thing that is different, is that there is now a 5 V Zener diode that regulates that part of the circuit to 5 V, and it has a capacitor on the output that goes to the VCC pin of the optocoupler.
This creates a 5 V linear power supply with admittedly not the greatest regulation, but its cheap and discrete. A side effect of this design is that the high side capacitor will now drain because of this Zener diode, and so either the switching frequency or bootstrap capacitor will need to be decently large. The values given below cause no issues in the simulation with basically 0 voltage droop from the capacitor, I'm just saying you shouldn't try to use this circuit at 1 Hertz with 99.999% duty cycle.
If this is a concern (it REALLY shouldn't be), take my advice above and google the Charge pump circuit that Texas Instruments provides.
LEVEL SHIFTING

source: me
The level shifting section changes the 5 V logic we used with the AND gate and steps it up to 12 V which is required to run the MOSFETs. You can see that the high side gets double-inverted as opposed to the low side, which only gets inverted once. Double inversion isn't terribly efficient and there are likely better methods of level shifting that involve a singular MOSFET, but I didn't want to troubleshoot that, and this worked.
POWER STAGE

source: me
This section is the most important one. It takes the low-current-capable input signal and turns it into a high-current signal capable of driving the MOSFETs.
The NPN on top of a PNP is referred to as a Class B amplifier, and it takes an input signal and uses two emitter-follower amplifiers to amplify the current using the Hfe of the transistor.
There is a problem with this however, the beta is high enough to switch the power NOSFET quickly on its own, but (for the low side MOSFET in particular), it struggles keeping the voltage at the output low when we are switching these massive voltages (240 V!!!) (look up dv/dt induced turn on to figure out why this is). So we have to add a MOSFET power stage after the NPN/PNP power stage. The section immediately after the NPN power stage is a P-channel MOSFET on top of an N-channel MOSFET. They have a gate resistor on the output between their respective drains, keeping shoot through current between these two MOSFETs to a minimum. Their outputs are incredibly high power and low impedance, so dv/dt induced turn on is kept to a minimum.
CONCLUDING REMARKS
I hope this was helpful to you, as you can see building a gate driver that can handle these high voltages and likely high currents is rather difficult (and PLEASE exercise caution when working with voltages that high...), so buying one is typically the better option.
I think TI offers isolated gate drivers that would be up for the task here, and they are about 10$ each for a half bridge one, so you have to make that decision.
The NPNs and PNPs in this circuit are ideal, you will have to replace them with whatever you wish to use in your circuit then adjust the dead-times as non-ideal NPNs/PNPs have some delay.
The MOSFETs chosen in the power stage were modest RDSon, low voltage MOSFETs (10-20 mΩ, 20-30 V) so that they are easy to drive from the NPN amp behind them. You do not have to use my specific MOSFETs, but choose something with a voltage rating of at least 20 V and a Qg of less than 20 nC if you can help it.
Remember to use Schmitt trigger comparators/logic buffers that are fast. Quantifying 'fast' is beyond the scope of this response, but it shouldn't take long to find one that has both of those features. For simulation purposes I chose two fast comparators in my LTspice list of components, but they're likely overkill and not required for the final design, so do your due diligence in finding an appropriate one.

For further research: take a peek at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=of_v2N5f788, it is Professor Sam Ben-Yaakov on youtube teaching about power mosfet drivers, and it's how I learned the theory.

Hello Sir, your comments are very valuable for me ı will change my circuit by considering your comments but ı just changed the npn transistor and the old spikes disappeared. Only thing left is the some continious small cut-offs as you can see at the last picture I added above. Is there anything that ı dont know about transistors ?
@theph

The video above by Professor Ben-Yaakov is pretty much all you'd need to know about gate driving (which is what you're trying to do). You replaced an ideal NPN with a real model of one, and your problem went away, which is not a good sign. Typically that means that there is something about this model that caused it to go away, which may or may not exist in the real transistor. For driving power mosfets, they have a gate charge that is required to be filled (like a capacitor) in order to turn on. Since the gate charge of your MOSFETs is so large, it needs powerful turn on circuitry.

Turning the mosfet on using a 1k pull-up resistor doesn't offer nearly enough charge per second (current), and that is an inherent flaw to this design. It means that when you try to turn any MOSFET on, it spends a bunch of time in the linear region (which is high resistance), so the current of the circuit runs through it and causes heating. My design above fixes this, as one with a dedicated gate driver would. When/If you build this circuit IRL, your mosfets will get very hot and may fry. I don't know what cutoffs you are referring to, there are a few things that could be causing issues @Mhan

Sir thanks a lot for your nice explanations. I am following your gate drive circuit. I have a question. I know how bootstrap is working but why the gate of transistor (optocoupler transistor) is connected to the 12 V ? it seems to me transistor is always conducting because of that 12 V. Although the diode is reverse biased by the time high side mosfet is on, isn't it gonna be fed by the capacitor this time. it is confusing a little bit. Could you explain the process of when bootstrap is used with optocoupler like in your circuit ?  @theph

Ah that's my bad, sorry. I updated all the drawings above to reflect the proper circuit now, and it includes a 5V regulator to give the optocoupler 5V instead of trying to find a 12V one.  It was SUPPOSED to give power to the VCC pin on the optocoupler, but I accidentally put it to the gate pin. curiously enough, the simulation still worked fine, but now it is correct (AND the simulation works for this one too). @Mhan

Thank you sir, do you have any part number/model for the optocoupler that is used in your circuit ? because I am trying to make same setup as yours  @theph

I used a model for the 6N137 optocoupler. Should be a fairly cost effective optocoupler and quite fast. Haven't used a real one of these yet, but the model works fine.

Sir can you share the ltspice model for the 6N137 because the ones that ı have found are not working in ltspice and many people has the same problem as far as ı searched for that part, thank you  @theph

I can share the links I used to get it: Here is the LTSpice pack from Alexej Bordodynov at his website: http://bordodynov.ltwiki.org/ If this is too sketchy to download from (I don't blame you at all for thinking that, but I did download it and it works), then you can use the LTSpice Groups.io page link. https://groups.io/g/LTspice It should be at the bottom of the page, and you need to make an account to access the files, whereas Bordodynov's stuff from his website is free to access. If you use Bordodynov's link, you get a TON of Spice models. There is also a ton of overlap between the two.

Sir thanks a lot for your amazing helps. I have some questions if you dont mind. why do we have a R7 pull-up resistor for Q5 (npn transistor in low side power stage) ? we have a base signal coming from the AND gate as well as connected to 12V with pull-up ? Doesn't this pull-up resistor make the Q5 base always open ? ı couldnt understand that point. I can understant it for Q6 in the high side power stage. because R2 pull-up resistor will be controlled by the transistor of optocoupler so its gonna be either 12 V or not. But ı couldnt understand it in low side power stage. @theph

Sir another thing that ı noticed is, ı randomly wanted to see the base and collector current of Q4 ( low side power stage transistor) and realised that when the base is triggered the base and collector currents just appear for a very small portion of the pulse. I add the pictures of this stiuation above. Do you have the same situation ? shouldn't the current stay on as long as the pulse is on ?   @theph

Look up how mosfets work to understand fully why this is. In short, the mosfet gate is a capacitor. When it is charged, it stays charged. When it is empty, it stays empty. To turn a mosfet on, you need to dump a certain amount of charge into the gate capacitor to raise the voltage really fast. Then, it stays on until you remove all that charge. If you look at Q10 which is the low side PNP, it sucks a bunch of current out when the wave goes low. This is intended behavior. The amplifier only needs current to turn the mosfets on and off, they don't need current to keep them on/off.

I missed your other comment. The pull up resistor R7 should be connected to 5V if connected at all, my bad. Logic gates with an "open collector/drain" design function like the optocoupler on the high side where they're either high impedance (off) or low impedance (on/ 0 Volts). If you use these, you need the pull up resistor R7 like the high side needed. If you use Push/Pull logic (that can go from 0 to 5V with no pull up), then R7 should be placed in between the AND gate and the base of Q5 to limit the current to Q5s base.

Thank you sir. I am trying to understand another point regarding Class B amplifier if you dont mind. To check the signal at base-emitter of Q4, ı realised that when Q5 is not conducting the signal going to base of Q4 is going between 11.367V and 0.142V ( not between 12V to 0V). I added another picture above to show how are my probs placed. The reason for that is it is 11.367 V because the pnp (Q10) is conducting so it has Veb drop. It is 0.142 V because prob is at the emitter of Q1,it has Vbe drop and its not directly touching to ground. Am ı thinking in a correct way ? @theph

A few things: R15 is WAY too big. 100 ohms is an order of magnitude too large, and you should never use 100 ohms on the gate to a mosfet unless youre directly driving a low Qg mosfet with a microcontroller, which you are not. You have the class B amplifier between them so that isn't an issue. R15 should be ~4 ohms. Second, M5 is the same as your power transistor(M4). This is the exact thing we were trying to avoid. Your power transistor has a Qg of 180nC. The reason we have the amplifiers before it is because it is hard to power, and you have put it in the amplifier, which defeats the purpose.

I said specifically in the "concluding remarks" section of my answer that you should use Mosfets with a VDS of at least 20V and a Qg less than 20nC. Your M5 has a Qg of 180nC, so it is 9x larger than it should be. The RDSon should also be below 20 milliOhms. As far as the class B amplifier goes, I don't know which waveform is which on your picture. Both arrows say "Red line", while one arrow is red and the other is black, and you have a red and blue line on the graph. They are also mislabeled. When Q10 (PNP) is on, the output will ALWAYS be low. The PNP always pulls the output to ground.

The voltage output of the class B amplifier will always be lower than the input (0V to 12V becomes 0.7V to 11.3V) as this is how emitter follower amplifiers work. All of the questions/mistakes you are asking/making are answered in the video by Sam Ben Yaakov that I linked as the first response to my answer. Its a long video, but if you don't want to watch it, then don't waste your time trying to build this circuit and just buy a gate driver. He also has a related video where he has different amplifiers he uses in different configurations. @Mhan

Usually its the parasitics in the FET models. You can replace your FET model with ideal voltage controlled switches to double check. You can try putting a gate-source resistor on the high side FETs to make sure it's not floating when it's not being driven. If there's a direct correlation between the frequency you're using, you can also try limiting the maximum time step the sim can use. Unrelated, 100ohm pull downs are very strong and may not need to be that strong.

Others have addressed the minutiae, I'll try and tackle the elephant in the room :)

Why does the signal get distorted like this when I increase the frequency? What could be the reason for this?

You're trying to design your own gate driver. That is fine for hobby/retro designs, but for use in anything even semi-serious, it's best avoided. Use a gate driver IC and you won't have those problems.
